# Highlight tabs in vim when expandtab is set

Tags: vim, indentation, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a recipe to make vim highlight tab characters with a given color, but *only* while the `expandtab` option is set? I know about `'listchars'`, but I'd like to be able to differentiate a "valid tab" from an "invalid tab".

Comment: What makes a tab "valid" or "invalid"?

Comment: "Invalid" is maybe a strong word... I mean a tab in a file that doesn't use tabs for indentation. The way I use `expandtab`, it always matches the file indentation settings.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom `:match` for tab characters based on `:autocmds`, like this:

```
autocmd WinEnter,VimEnter *
\   if &expandtab |
\       silent! call matchadd('Error', '\t',  10, 31337) |
\   else |
\       silent! call matchdelete(31337) |
\   endif
```

(For simplicity, this uses a hard-coded ID.)

Alternatively, you could use a plugin like my [IndentConsistencyCop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690), which checks for both inconsistent indentation and mismatches of the buffer and its settings, and by default also highlights the wrong lines. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)